# How to toggle the visibility of a relative layout & an image view inside a list view row?

Tags: android, visibility, custom-lists

I am having a list view which contains an image view at the end of each row. What i want to do is when i click on it an other layout must be made visible. By layout i mean that i am having a relative layout consisting of an image view & a text view for every row of list view whose visibility is initially set to GONE.

I have tried with following code in my adapter class but the relative is visible after i clicked on my image view 2 times & the relative layout is not opened on correct position. Also when the relative layout becomes visible, i am migrating on the next activity on its click listener.

```
holder.rowImageView.setTag(position);
        holder.rowImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int position = (Integer) view.getTag();
                holder.rowRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        holder.rowRelativeLayout.setTag(position);
        holder.rowRelativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), OrderActivity.class);
                intent .putExtra("ProductId", gettersSetters.getVoucherId());
                intent .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent );
            }
        });
```

someone please suggest that what i am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your position from tag is not correct. You can check this code:

```
    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        if( convertView == null ){
            ...
            holder.imageView.setTag(position);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.rowImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int position = (int) view.getTag();
                View rowEffect = getViewByPosition(position, (ListView)parent);
               rowEffect.findViewById(R.id.rowRelativeLayout).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        holder.rowRelativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ...
            }
       });
   }



private View getViewByPosition(int pos, ListView listView) {
    final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listView.getChildCount() - 1;

    if (pos < firstListItemPosition || pos > lastListItemPosition ) {
        return listView.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listView);
    } else {
        final int childIndex = pos - firstListItemPosition;
        return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: This did not work for me. When i click on image view of any row the relative layout of last row becomes visible.

Comment: Yes, because at this time, the holder object is run to last row 's position, so the idea is "you need to find the rowRelativeLayout that has the same position of clicked image". You can see my edited answer. Ofcourse, this is not the best solution, you can get more investigation for better solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving the perfect answer. +1 reserved for you.

Comment: I need one more help. I want to make only one Relative Layout visible at a time. How to do so? Means if i click on an image view & a relative layout is previously visible then it must hide itself.

Comment: I just only give you the idea : 
1) When a rowRelativeLayout is visible --> save the Position in a global variable. 
2) When click imageView--> get view from above saved Position and hide its rowRelativeLayout --> show the current effect(this is done in old code). Note*: the position and saved position must be inside the visible row on screen [firstListItemPosition, lastListItemPosition]. 
3) Set Listview onScroll listener, when its scroll, hide rowRelativeLayout from saved position.